# run script when var equals any listed in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

not sure why this isn't working for me , i have a script embedded into about 100 different third party sites , each of those sites prints a var in its page source to determine its uniqueID

The var printed to each page is

```
var league_id = '43570';
```

the 5 digit number changes depending on the league_id for that site.

I want to execute a function for certain sites that have a league_id
The following works fine , but my list may be 100 or more league_id

```
if ( league_id === '43570' || league_id === '10065' ) {
    console.log(league_id + " League Validated");
} else {
    console.log(league_id + " League Not Validated");
}
```

So i wanted to place in an array , but my below 2 efforts have failed

```
if ([43570,10065,61,3902].indexOf(league_id) > -1) {
    console.log(league_id + " League Validated");
} else {
    console.log(league_id + " League Not Validated");
}

if([43570,10065,61,3902].includes(league_id)) {
    console.log(league_id + " League Validated");
} else {
    console.log(league_id + " League Not Validated");
}
```

Comment: You're comparing strict equality of string ('43570') with number (43570) in your indexOf or includes

Comment: ya just realized i need to parse it right after i posted

Answer (score 2):

From the MDN docs:

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

You're comparing a variable of type `number` to one of type `string`.

Answer (score 1):

ok dummy me , i realized i need to parse the number

```
const parsed = parseInt(league_id);
if ([43570,10065,61].indexOf(parsed) > -1) {
    console.log(league_id + " League Validated");
} else {
    console.log(league_id + " League Not Validated");
}
```